# SugarCRM - how to add additional column in Gantt Grid View for Project Tasks?

Tags: sugarcrm, gantt-chart

I found here http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f6/custom-columns-gantt-charts-31205/ how to add columns to gantt view in project tasks (View Gantt) - to change EditGridView.tpl file but I think it is not upgrade safe.
Is it possible to add some column here or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file override is put in the custom/ directory, you should be upgrade-safe.

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer but if I put  modified EditGridView.tpl file in crm/custom/modules/Projects nothing happens. That is the problem. And user from sugar forum said he put it in /crm/modules/Projects do you know how to solve this? If I add some column and put that file in custom module nothing happens. developer mode is turned on