# Populating $beanList, $beanFiles and $moduleList for a Distributed Module

Tags: php, module, javabeans, sugarcrm

I want to create a SugarCRM module for redistribution.  Where should I populate `$beanList`, `$beanFiles`, and `$moduleList`?

That is, if I use the module generator to create a SugarCRM module, the system will auto generate the following file

```
custom/application/Ext/Include/modules.ext.php
```

which populates the three global variables `$beanList`, `$beanFiles`, and `$moduleList` with something like this (assuming a module name of `pshw_Helloworld`.

```
$beanList['pshw_Helloworld'] = 'pshw_Helloworld';
$beanFiles['pshw_Helloworld'] = 'modules/pshw_Helloworld/pshw_Helloworld.php';
$moduleList[] = 'pshw_Helloworld';
```

This works great for a local system — but if I wanted to redistribute a module (offered for downloading online, deployed to multiple offices, etc.), should I be instructing people to populate the `modules.ext.php` or `modules_override.php` file themselves?  Or is there a more elegant way of redistributing a SugarCRM module that uses a bean?

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15259436/76772  This gives the full code for a very basic, redistributable, SugarCRM plug-in.  This doesn't include any Bean files, but might help you to understand the basic structure of a redistributable package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done automatically by including a manifest.php in your module zip. The Module Loader will read the manifest and create these entries for you. The key is the 'beans' key in the $installdefs array. More info can be found here: [Introduction to the Manifest File](http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/Module_Loader/Introduction_to_the_Manifest_File#beans)

Comment: +1 for good information — but I think you threw me in the deep end.  What is this modules.zip file you speak of?  Is there a tutorial on creating this file anywhere?  Once I have a modules.zip, how would someone who wanted to use my module load this into their system?

Comment: IMHO the best way to learn how to create a mass distributable module is to see how folks have already done it on SugarForge. SugarCRM comes with a tool found under Admin called Module Loader where these zip files can be uploaded and installed. For a tutorial, this is a good start: http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/Module_Loader