# How do you include custom javascript

Tags: javascript, email, module, sugarcrm

I'd like to be able to include custom javascript for the Emails modules in sugarcrm so that I can run some javascript on the email composition page. However that module doesn't seem to load the *viewdefs.php files. Does anyone know how to do this?
Is there a file I can add in the custom directory instead of modifying the core Emails module code directly, so that it will be upgrade safe. Thanks in advance

I can include custom javascript files in other modules by adding it to the include array element in $vardefs in custom/modules//metadata/editviewdefs.php or detailviewdefs.php etc. but that doesn't seem to work for the email module.

Answer (score 2):

Please see:  [SugarCRM- How to get POPUP when click on Save button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254673/sugarcrm-how-to-get-popup-when-click-on-save-button/15259436#15259436)

My entire answer is all about getting custom JavaScript to load in any arbitrary module in SugarCRM in an upgrade-safe manner.

Comment: The after_ui_frame logic hook is the key piece in Kyle's answer. You can define this in custom/modules/logic_hooks.php.

Comment: I created a module as described in your link.  Thanks fore that info, it is helpful, but it doesn't work for quick create view. When I click the compose email button from within the context of another module's detail view, and the quick create modal window comes up, my php file (the one that corresponds to this one in your example "custom_popup_js_include.php") executes (I know this because I added some output to a log file) but the javascript I'm outputting from within that file doesn't get loaded on the page.